# Why are Doctype declarations split on two lines?

Tags: html

I know there's more important questions to discuss probably, but at the cost of appearing a fool, I'd like an answer ;-)

Take this for instance:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Is it to comply to the 80 column standard? Also, i normally use single quotes in my HTML as they're easier on the eye, does it make any difference to browsers? Will it send IE6 in quirks mode putting it on one line and single-quoting attributes?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just line-wrapping.

Also, XML will take either quote mark, but convention is the double quote.

Comment: FYI: also HTML Tidy application split DOCTYPE in two lines, I've never understood the reason for this. I agree with Alnitak.
In my HTML file I personally use only one single line for DOCTYPE.

Answer (score 2):

My guess it that its for readability.

AFAIK, it does not have to be on two line, all of our website have it on a single line, as does SO.